# 2 Teamcity Web applications have problems accessing git repository

Tags: teamcity

I have 2 separate Teamcity web application instances running on separate servers accessing the same git repository.

This seems to be causing issues with the VCS root configuration.

The specific error message is:

```
Error collecting changes for VCS repository ... 'git fetch' command failed... 301 Moved permanently
```

I get this message for every build configuration with every teamcity project in my installation.

I must maintain 2 separate teamcity application instances on different servers - one that builds Microsoft Windows software artifacts and the other that build Linux based artifacts.

The only workaround that I currently have for this problem is to delete the VCS root and set it up again - only to discover that the next day the problem is back.

I can't keep doing this forever - there must be a better way to address this.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working with Jetbrains support, they root caused the issue to the use of http:// in the github URL instead of https://.

So, IOW, when you specify a github repository URL, you must use https:// in a temmcity VCS root configuration.